# Как насильно обновить инпут через js?

Tags: javascript, html

На фрилансе я часто выполняю задания, связанные с обработкой текста в инпутах, и часто пишу юзерскрипты себе в помощь. И заметил, что если я меняю через свой скрипт текст в инпуте, у меня он меняется, но не сохраняется при отправке данных на сервер. То есть мне нужно клацнуть что-то в инпуте, чтобы текст обновился (я так понимаю, чтобы вызывалось событие onChanged). Условный код:

```
let inp = document.querySelector("#input_id");
inp.value = "Что-то поменял в тексте";
```

Есть ли какой-то способ насильно обновить инпут? (использую tampermonkey)

Comment:  Не насилуйте инпут. (сорри, не удержался)

Comment: скорее всего проблема где-то в аяксе, который не те данные берёт для отправки на сервер. Текущее изменение value затрагивает всё нужное и проблем быть не должно

Comment: Если я, например, изменю скриптом инпут, потом просто клацну в инпуте пробел и удалю его, то при отправке отправится вместе с изменениями с моего скрипта, но если чисто изменю со скрипта (не трогая руками инпут), то он мои изменения со скрипта не забирает.

Comment: Полный воспроизводимый пример в студию пжлст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно событие `onchange`, то можете сами его вызвать.

```
let inp = document.querySelector("#input_id");
inp.value = "Что-то поменял в тексте";

inp.dispatchEvent(new Event('change',{bubbles:true}));
```

Comment: Крсивое решение. А исходная проблема, скорее всего, была вызвана тем, что ajax не обрабатывал value инпута, а просто по событию onChange создавал копию существующего на этот момент в инпуте значения.